# PHP will save files to one folder but not another

Tags: php, apache, centos

I am making a phonegap app that includes uploading to a linux server running the LAMP stack.

I have a file called *upload.php* which contains the following code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$new_image_name = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".jpg";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

and inside */var/www/html/* I have a folder called uploads with 777 permissions just for testing purposes. This code works perfectly and saves the files in */var/www/html/uploads/*. I then created another folder called images within the html folder and it also has 777 permissions but the file will refuse to save in this folder when I run this version of *upload.php*:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$new_image_name = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".jpg";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

It may be worth noting that I can also save to directories inside */var/www/html/uploads/* such as */var/www/html/uploads/images/*

Comment: Check ownership of both the folders.

Comment: Both folders are set up with the exact same permissions and owners @akshaypjoshi

Comment: is there in `/var/www/` or in `/var/www/html/` or in `/var/www/html/uploads/` an `.htaccess` file (hidden)?

Comment: @Andra no there aren't any hidden files in any of those directories

Comment: permissions in the virtual host config file?

Comment: I'm just running it off a virtual machine but both were created using root user and were given 777 permissions @Andra

Comment: Leaving aside the gaping security hole in your application, have you checked writing a file instead of moving a file? Are you using a mandatory access control system?

Comment: @symcbean I am aware of the security risks I was just using those permissions for testing purposes. SELinux was blocking access to other directories

Comment: @Theo: what you propose above gives an attacker full control over the code executing in the webserver and its got **nothing** to do with the permissions. Have a google for double extension LFI